# how can I save struct in file .... C lang

Tags: c, file, pointers

I'd like to save a struct in a file. 
I'd like to realize a function which makes this work. 
I tried this code but it didn't work.

```
struct utilisateur   // enregestrement pour sauvegarder les details de l utilisateur
{
 char nom[20];
 char prenom[20];
 int place;
 char depart[20];
 char arrive[20];
 char sexe;
 int nwagon;
};

struct utilisateur utilis;
struct utilisateur *Table[48];

void crea_fich(struct utilisateur *Tutilis)
// creation un fichier, vous introduiez le nom, et le sotcker par enreg
{
    FILE *f;
    if (f!==0)
    {
         printf("error in the name of file \n");
         exit(1);
    }
    if (f=fopen(futilis,"w")==Null){
         fprint("We can't creat file \n");
         exit(1);
    }
    else{
        f=fopen("futilis.dat","wb");
        fwrite(Tutilis ,sizeof(utilisateur),1,f);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of noise in that code snippet, not to mention formatting problems (and the declaration of Table looks strange). How is the result of the fwrite different from what you were expecting, assuming your actual code gets that far?

Comment: Hi. Can you put a little text formatting in your question? It'll make it much easier to read.

Comment: What are you trying to do with "if (f!==0)"? Firstly, "f" is uninitialized, so using it at that point is just plain wrong. Secondly, there is no operator "!=="; you mean to use "!=".

Comment: I hate to say this, but you probably want to write your code in English, as it is globally the most widely used language, and will -- therefore -- maximize the number of people who can help you or collaborate with you on your code.

Comment: Do you want to write out the struct in human-readable form, or just a machine-readable dump that may not be portable?

Answer (score 6):

No. You need to write out your data members individually, one at a time. You should not just blindly copy the memory representation of your struct into the file output buffer (which it is clear you are  trying to do). Writing files that way will cause the files to non-portable (they won't be readable except on the platform that they were written), because of the endian-ness and the platform-specific padding of the struct elements.

Comment: well, he never said that portability was required, so there is nothing explicitly wrong with the notion of writing structs directly to the filesystem. I've know one or two language front-ends, for instance, that did exactly that with their parsed-tree data.

Comment: There are some appropriate use cases. I'm trying to write to IgorPxp file

Answer (score 6):

Just a simple example :)

```
// your struct
struct Data
{
    int first;
    double second;
    char third[10];
};
```

Then write the struct!

```
struct Data data = {22, 4.0, "Hi"};
FILE* output;

output = fopen("Data.dat", "wb");

fwrite(&data, sizeof(data), 1, output);

fclose(output);
```

Finally read the data from the file you created!

```
struct Data data;
FILE* input;

input = fopen("Data.dat", "rb");

fread(&data, sizeof(data), 1, input);

// you got the data from the file!

fclose(input);
```

Binary files are nightmares if not written and read wisely. You have to take care of a lot of things about the architecture where the file was created and where will it be read. Endianess and size of variables are the most important. Also, If you have pointers inside your `struct`, the pointer that will be written to the file not the actual data where the pointer points to. Sorry, I didn't edit your code because it is full of compilation errors :)

I deleted my first answer because it was so wrong, sorry :)

Comment: This is just a nitpick, but you opened the file in "r" mode and wrote binary data ("r" is text, "rb" is binary). While this won't make a difference in linux, it might when this code is run in windows, FYI.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, and then if that's not doing what you want, try explaining how it differs from what you want.

```
void crea_fich(struct utilisateur *Tutilis)
{
   FILE *f;
   size_t nwritten;

   f = fopen("futilis.dat","wb");

   if (f == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file for writing.\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   nwritten = fwrite(Tutilis, sizeof Tutilis[0], 1, f);
   fclose(f);

   if (nwritten < 1)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Writing to file failed.\n");
      exit(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: This (and the converse function using `fread()`) will work on any one machine architecture; it is not, however, portable to other architectures.  This probably doesn't matter in the context, but it is worth mentioning for completeness.

Answer (score 6):

Michael S is right; using `fwrite` with a struct is wildly nonportable.  But let's assume you don't care about that and you want something easy to write that will work.

The problem in your code is that you've broken the Golden Rule of `sizeof`: **never use `sizeof` with a type name**.  Instead you should use `sizeof` with an lvalue, and almost always with the *dereference of another argument*.  Thus

```
Tutilis = malloc (sizeof (*Tutilis));
  ...
fwrite(Tutilis, sizeof (*Tutilis), 1, f);
```

If you follow this recipe it's much harder to get the size wrong.

Comment: I would hardly call that a "Golden Rule." Tons of code out and about today calls sizeof on non lvalues. Microsoft's own MSDN website shows how to call it on a type-name. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s7x1k91.aspx

Comment: @James: It's perfectly legal, it's just not a very robust programming practice. You wouldn't jump off a cliff just because MSDN showed you how, would you? :-)

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old post, but it comes up when people search for this information, so I'll give my own solution.

This is basically what I have used in one of my games.  I actually have some extra library specific code in my own function for dialogs, but this is essentially it.  I write data individually.  I don't think I have a struct for this data, but there is no difference, just write your individual struct members separately.  As mentioned, it's better this way.

```
// returns 1 if successful, 0 if not
int savemap(const char *map_name)
{
   FILE *file = NULL;

   // open the file in write binary mode
   file = fopen(map_name, "wb");

   // always check return values to see if it was opened okay
   if(file == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file for writing.\n");
      return 0;
   }

   // write file ID, version and pills
   fwrite(MAP_ID, sizeof(char), strlen(MAP_ID)+1, file);
   fwrite(&MAP_VER, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
   fwrite(&pills, sizeof(unsigned short), 1, file);

   // write the map data (unsigned int map[315])
   fwrite(&map, sizeof(unsigned int), 315, file);

   // never forget to close the file
   fclose(file);

   return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look over the symbol names first, like `NULL` and `fprint`, not to mention that weird `\0`. As an additional thought, you should close the file after writing to make sure it gets flushed to disk, and double check that `futilis` variable is a `char*` that contains a valid, writeable path.