# .dat structured file handling in C (manual ?)

Tags: c

Hello I just wanna ask where can we get a relevant manual about .dat file handling in C not C++. I was googling around and It really me a lot time. So I come because I know there's a lot of expert here.

Hope you could me.

Even just a simple example of read, edit, add and delete. (CRUD)

Wow thanks for the answer man however I tried to save and retrieve the data.
it didn't gave me the correct data during saving.

1. I wrote a data in the file.

   ```
   typedef struct{
      char name[50];
      int age;
   } PERSON;
   ```

int main(){

```
            PERSON p;
            FILE *f;

           strcpy(p.name,"John"); 
           p.age = 25;

           f = fopen("test.dat","wb+");
           fwrite(&p,1,sizeof(p),f);

           fclose(f);

           return 0;
}
```

1. Retrieved the data from the file.

   ```
   typedef struct{
   char name[50];
   int age;
   ```

   } PERSON;

   int main()
   {
       PERSON p;
      FILE *f;

   f = fopen("comets$system:test.dat","wb+");

   fread(p,sizeof(p),1,f);

   fclose(f);

   printf("Name from the persons is %s",&p.name);

   return 0;
   }

but the output is this

```
Name from the person is Ëz
```

Comment: Which particular sub-species of `.dat` file did you have in mind?  On which platform?  The one I'm most familiar with (Informix C-ISAM) is probably not what you have in mind.

Comment: Ahm I'm currently coding in Open VMS platform. Don't exactly know that there's a different type of. Can you give me some information of standard or what you have mind. Maybe I can use that. thanks

Comment: @PeterG. Ahm if you're asking about .dat file you can view this. this has a simple example of adding a data in a DAT file http://www.learn-programming.za.net/programming_c_learn10.html. However I want to know about reading, deleting and editing.

Comment: The suffix `.dat` is used in general for data files.  Without more context, it tells you exactly nothing about the content of the file or how it's arranged.  It's *probably* not going to be text, but that's no certain.  It's like that `fread()` is going to be part of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data items are described by a C structure of a fixed size that's typedef'ed something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  ... // fill in the missing details
} MyDataItem;
```

and that your data files consist of these MyDataItem's...

Use `fopen(FileName, "wb")` to create an empty file for the purpose of writing MyDataItem's to it (if there's a file by this name before this call, it will be overwritten and all data from it will be lost).

Use `fopen(FileName, "rb")` to open an existing file for reading only.

Use `fopen(FileName, "rb+")` to open an existing file for reading or writing/updating.

Use `fopen(FileName, "wb+")` to create a new file for the purpose of writing/updating or reading (if there's a file by this name before this call, it will be overwritten and all data from it will be lost).

Use `fopen(FileName, "ab")` to open an existing file or create a new file for appending data at its end.

Use `fopen(FileName, "ab+")` to open an existing file or create a new file for appending data at its end and reading/writing/updating it.

Use `fclose(FileStreamPointer)` to close a previously opened file when you're done working with it.

Use `fseek(FileStreamPointer, StructureIndex*sizeof(MyDataItem), SEEK_SET)` to prepare to read or (over)write StructureIndex'th MyDataItem in an existing and open file. This sets the current file position for reading/writing. Note that fread() and fwrite(), the functions that read and write data from/to files, advance the current position by the amount of the read/written data.

Use `fread(PointerToMyDataItemStructure, 1, sizeof(MyDataItem), FileStreamPointer)` to read a MyDataItem.

Use `fwrite(PointerToMyDataItemStructure, 1, sizeof(MyDataItem), FileStreamPointer)` to write a MyDataItem.

Use `fstat()` or `stat()` to find out the size of a file. These are not standard in C, they are extensions (POSIX or other).

Deleting a MyDataItem at the very end of a file can be achieved by calling `ftruncate()`, `truncate()` and similar functions, but they are not standard in C, they are extensions (POSIX or other).

There is no standard/common function to delete a portion of a file at its beginning or somewhere in the middle of it. You'll have to either create a new file and copy/write into it only the data that you want to keep (then delete the old file and possibly rename the new one) OR copy the data in the file from after the portion you want to delete with fread() and fwrite() over this deleted portion and then truncate the file.

Use `remove()` to delete a file.

Use `rename()` to rename a file.

Use `tmpnam()`+`fopen()` or `tmpfile()` to create a temporary file.

Your OS may provide additional useful functions for file I/O.

See documentation for details.

Comment: Aha.. I found this very useful link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203667/how-can-i-save-struct-in-file-c-lang it demonstrates the basic reading and writing of data in a DAT file. I hope I could find delete and modify. :)