# C++ How do I use a structure after I Zeroed its memory?

Tags: c++, memory, struct

Hello when I Zeroed out the structure here

```
struct hudelem_color{ byte r, g, b, a; };
```

I cannot use it anymore so what would I do if I wanted to reuse it after i did

`ZeroMemory(&hudelem_color, sizeof hudelem_color)`

Comment: What do you mean "cannot use it anymore"? Please provide possible error messages, and more complete code.

Comment: Oh, and you do have a *variable* named `hudelem_color`?

Comment: It is not wrong to memset a POD type, so I don't see your problem.

Comment: Ok. So when I free the structures memory when I get back into the game I want to use the structure again.

Comment: I'm not sure what POD means.

Comment: So you want to restore the structure after you quit and re-started your game?

Comment: POD = Plain Old Data

Comment: @Andreas Yes thats exactly what I want to do.

Comment: You need to write your structure into a file before exitting the program, and load it again from the file after restarting. This should give you a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203667/how-can-i-save-struct-in-file-c-lang. And, you should really rephrase your question and say that you want to do exactly that ...

Comment: You really should use `memset` instead of having your `ZeroMemory`....

Comment: `memset` isn't too nice either. [just assign `{0}`](http://ideone.com/HrcZmM). That works correctly for all POD types.

Answer (score 3):

hudelem_color is a struct/type, you need to define an object for it.

```
hudelem_color clr;
ZeroMemory(&clr, sizeof (hudelem_color));
```

it's meaningless to memset a struct definition.

Comment: But it would be simpler to just write `hudelem_color clr { 0 }`;

Answer (score 1):

With your example structure

```
struct hudelem_color{ byte r, g, b, a; };
```

Then you can have e.g. this loop

```
bool game_continue = true;

while (game_continue)
{
    hudelem_color color;
    memset(&color, 0, sizeof(color));

    // Use the `color` variable, do whatever you want with it
}
```

Each iteration of the loop you define a new instance of the structure, and zero the memory of it. This is not strictly *reuse* of the structure instance, as a new instance is created every iteration in the loop.

You can also have

```
hudelem_color color;

while (game_continue)
{
    memset(&color, 0, sizeof(color));

    // Use the `color` variable, do whatever you want with it
}
```

The above loop works almost as the previous one, but instead of creating a new instance every iteration one is created before the loop and then actually reused in each iteration.

I would personally recommend the first variant though. And if you do this, why not simple add a default constructor that clears out the fields, then you don't have to do it manually every iteration:

```
struct hudelem_color
{
    byte r, g, b, a;

    hudelem_color() : r(0), g(0), b(0), a(0) {}
};

// ...

while (game_continue)
{
    hudelem_color color;

    // Here all fields of the structure variable `color` will be zero
    // Use the structure as you see fit
}
```

Comment: Would this be a safe way to do it because I am kinda iffy about the loop

Comment: @Konroi What do you mean by "a safe way"? If the first (or last) statement in the loop is to zero out the structure, then the rest of the loop will have a zeroed structure.

Comment: Ohhh I see now haha sorry. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, go for it.   You can totally re-use it.  after ZeroMemory you've got a hudelem_color with r,g,b, and a all zero.  Just use it.

Some code that needs high performance while reusing thousands of little objects uses a pattern called 'object pools', google for more info...